# SQL - How to check if an element appears in one column but not in another

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you check in a query if a element appears in one column but not in another? For example I have 2 columns with some IDs

```
**Route**
+---------+--------------+
| StartID | DestinationID|
+---------+--------------+
|  9016   |     1015     |
|  9015   |     7628     |
|  1015   |     1500     |
|  1023   |     1500     |
|  1023   |     1015     |
|  7628   |     9022     |
|  7628   |     1500     |
|  6700   |     9016     |
|  6700   |     1500     |
|  9015   |     9022     |
+---------+--------------+
```

How would I return any ID's that appear in the first column but not in the second? Thanks

edit: The query actually wants me to return the number of distinct ID's, for some reason when I put in

```
SELECT DISTINCT StartID
FROM Route R WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Route I WHERE I.DestinationID = R.StartID);
```

The result is:

```
+---------+
| StartID |
+---------+
|  1023   |
|  6700   | 
|  9015   |
+---------+
```

But when I put in

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(StartID)
FROM Route R WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Route I WHERE I.DestinationID = R.StartID);
```

The result is:

```
+----------------+
| count(StartID) |
+----------------+
|       6        |   
+----------------+
```

Does anyone know why this is and how to write a query to return the correct result? (3) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`.

```
select distinct startid 
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where t.startid=destinationid)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `not exists()`:

```
select *
from route r
where not exists (
  select 1
  from route i
  where i.DestinationId = r.StartId
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join, and you can return all rows where the join does not succeed:

```
select r.StartID
from
  route r left join route b
  on r.StartID = b.DestinationId
where
  b.DestinationId is null
```